# How are, or should, non-working HTML menu items with only working submenus be identified?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

A typical wordpress menu has one menu item with a top-level target of #, going nowhere, to allow for its multiple, working submenus which do go to targeted URLs.

Philosophically, is the onus on me to visually signify to users that this top level menu item is a dead menu item, with no target, so they don't select it and wait for a change that will never come?

What design feature can or needs to be used to signify a non-working menu item which has only working submenus?

Or is it worth pondering at all?

Comment: I don't like hover menus, for my work I created a click menu and each menu item that has children has an indicator + or chevron to indicate children (I don't like mystery nav either). Click the menu item, & the submenu opens, click again or outside, it closes. If the person using the theme has a regular link with children, then I write an error to the front end that is ugly. Their instructions are clear. Otherwise, if you use a hover menu, it would be better to not use # & have the top level link to the first page of that section & you repeat that link as the first menu item in the sub menu.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting thought. You could change the cursor on hover to indicate text rather than the pointer for a link.

Answer (score 0):

The onus is absolutely on the designer & developer to implement proper UX. An ideal design would effectively communicate the difference between a unlinked dropdown and traditional link.

Check out how [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) does this with their main navigation. A prominent, eye-catching dropdown appears on hover. Clicking the main, parent link closes the dropdown. Clicking again re-opens the dropdown.